# How to estimate uncertainty (% error) of prediction from existing linear regression model on new inputs?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression

Say I have an independent variable (x) and a dependent variable (y) for which I modeled the relationship using a simple linear regression (ols). I then use this model to predict on new x-inputs (out of sample data). How would I get the percent uncertainty (error) for each prediction on new x inputs?

Example python code:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

## Generate test data
x = np.array([ 11.56014355, 107.27786033,  22.71480777,  29.01184381,
         0.79849564,  98.21190682,  51.07570173,   1.50033622,
        26.59511826,   0.3202299 ,  47.2756623 , 112.2986999 ,
        58.79240058])
y = np.array([ 25.86765, 268.65924,  48.85899,  86.50794,   3.43958, 230.97228,
       147.39168,   5.25603,  73.42733,   3.10752, 129.9112 , 268.29192,
       119.41919])

## Get linear regression results
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

## Now, I need to use this regression to predict on new input data.
# How to get % uncertainty for each new prediction from data below?
new_x = np.array([40.1, 63.8, 87.4])
```

OLS Results:
     **coef  std err** 
x     2.44   0.059

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

Comment: Yes, but it does not explain how to get the % error.